# Cout Overload Operating for multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, multiple-inheritance, cout, diamond-problem

I have 4 classes, Vehicle, PassengerVehicle, CargoVehicle, and CrewHauler. I will draw a diagram and put data members inside the parenthesizes.

```
                                 Vehicle
                            (model, brand, year)
                        /                         \
                       /                           \
(model, brand, year, doors, seats)          (model, brand, year, capacity)
           PassengerVehicle                           CargoVehicle
                        \                         /
                         \                       /
                                 CrewHauler
                  (model, brand, year, doors, seats, capacity)
```

Everything works out fine. But when I try to write the overload operator "cout <<" for CrewHauler, it keeps saying that "the object has type qualifier that are not compatible with the member function "passengerVehicle::getDoors"" and underlines *CrewHauler*.getDoors() as well as *CrewHauler*.getSeats().
**How should I fix it?**
Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;

CrewHauler::CrewHauler(std::string brand, std::string model, int year, 
                       int doors, int seats, double capacity) : 
                       passengerVehicle(brand, model, year, doors, seats), 
                       cargoVehicle(brand, model, year, capacity)
{
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const CrewHauler& CrewHauler)
{
    output << "------- CrewHauler -------" << endl
        << "Brand: " << CrewHauler.Vehicle::getBrand() << endl
        << "Model: " << CrewHauler.Vehicle::getModel() << endl
        << "Year: " << CrewHauler.Vehicle::getYear() << endl 
        << "Doors:" << CrewHauler.getDoors() << endl
        << "Seats:" << CrewHauler.getSeats() << endl;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: this is my code in CrewHauler.cpp and I already included "CrewHauler.h"

Comment: You need to mark the `getDoor`, and other functions you use in `operator<<` as const.

Comment: I just ran into another problem... Now it's saying "ambigous access of 'getBrand', 'getModel', and 'getYear'....

Comment: You'll need to mark all those functions const *across* the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, I already mark all the getters const, there is no red underlines but I still can't run it...

Comment: You'll need to provide sufficient code for us to reproduce the error.

Comment: Here are my getters:

`string Vehicle::getBrand() const
{
 return brand;
}

string Vehicle::getModel() const
{
 return model;
}

int Vehicle::getYear() const
{
 return year;
}`

Comment: Please add this to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include all the class definitions.  Do all classes have `model` members?  How is `Vehicle` inherited (is it a virtual base class)?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: i'm sorry, I'm new to the community

Comment: This is not enough information to help.  You need to post enough code that it can be compiled and we see the exact error you're asking about, but also, strip the example to include nothing that isn't essential to demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your entities like this (assuming non-virtual public inheritance and public methods), and I got 2 compile errors. The first was about the ambiguity of the method call, since the complier doesn't know what path to use to reach `Vechicle::getBrand`, the second was saying that it could not convert `const CrewHauler` type to `Vehicle&` type.

```
class Vehicle {
public:
    int getBrand() { return 1; }
};

class PassengerVehicle : public Vehicle {
public:
    int getBrand() { return 2; }
};

class CargoVehicle : public Vehicle {
public:
    int getBrand() { return 3; }
};

class CrewHauler : public PassengerVehicle, public CargoVehicle {
public:
    int getBrand() { return 4; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& _o, const CrewHauler& _h) {
    return _o << _h.Vehicle::getBrand();
}
```

To solve the first one, I simply specified the entire path to follow for the compiler to reach the desired `getBrand` method: `_h.CargoVehicle::Vehicle::getBrand()` (you can also use `_h.PassengerVehicle::Vehicle::getBrand()`, since the endpoint is the same).

I don't think there is a way to solve the second error, which is due to the base method call, using only one operator overloading that can take both lvalues and rvalues of your entity type, therefore I split it into 2, one taking a non-const lvalue-reference type (`CrewHauler&`) and the other taking a (non-const) rvalue-reference type (`CrewHauler&&`):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& _o, CrewHauler& _h) {
    return _o << _h.CargoVehicle::Vehicle::getBrand() << " lvalue reference";
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& _o, CrewHauler&& _h) {
    return _o << _h.PassengerVehicle::Vehicle::getBrand() << " rvalue reference";
}
```

I wrote this sample code to test it out:

```
auto ch = CrewHauler();
std::cout << CrewHauler() << std::endl << ch;
```

which will output the following, as expected:

> 1 rvalue reference
>   1 lvalue reference

Hope this can help.